# state flow in recycler view kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, viewmodel

My app has `single activity` that host all other fragments
I use `Navigation graph` with `SafeArgs` to navigate from fragment to another.
My `homeFrag` populate recycler view from `Room Database` with help of Repository, ViewModel and StateFlow.
currently all works fine and homeFrag send `paperId: UUID` properly to other `DialogFragments`
except that when I remove all items from recycler and add new items the first item in recycler is the only one that not recieved by other dialog fragments
Even with app restart, only the first item return null on dialogfragments but not in recycler (which show correct data)
I'm using `collect` for getting paper instance in dialogfragments

**home Fragment**

```
package com.asadi.paprr

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.asadi.paprr.databinding.HomeFragBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.emptyFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.File

const val PICK_PDF_FILE = 2

class homeFrag : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: HomeFragBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val papersListViewModel: PapersListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = HomeFragBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                papersListViewModel.papers.collect { papers ->

                    if (papers === emptyFlow<Paper>()) {
                        // DO NOTHING
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Empty Flow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "flow content is: $papers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        binding.recyclerView.adapter =
                            RecyclerAdapter(papers,
                                { paperid ->
                                    findNavController().navigate(
                                        homeFragDirections.showEditDialogFrag(paperid)
                                    )
                                },
                                { paperId ->
                                    findNavController().navigate(
                                        homeFragDirections.previewPdfAction(paperId)
                                    )
                                },
                                { paper ->
                                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                                        papersListViewModel.removePaper(paper)
                                        removeOnClick(paper)


                                    }
                                })
                    }


                }
            }

        }


        // ADD MANUALLY BUTTON LISTENER
        binding.addManauallyBtn.setOnClickListener {
            addNewPaperDialog()
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }


    fun removeOnClick(paper: Paper) {

        val fileName = paper.fileName

        val file = File(context?.filesDir, "myPdfs/$fileName")
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete()
        }

    }

    private fun addNewPaperDialog() {

        findNavController().navigate(
            homeFragDirections.showAddDialog()
        )

    }

}
```

**Dialog fragment :**

```
package com.asadi.paprr

import android.app.Dialog
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.OpenableColumns
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.fragment.app.*
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.flowWithLifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
import androidx.room.Room
import com.asadi.paprr.databinding.AddEntryDialogBinding
import com.asadi.paprr.databinding.EditEntryDialogBinding
import com.asadi.paprr.databinding.PdfViewerFragmentBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.distinctUntilChanged
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.filterNotNull
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.firstOrNull
import java.io.File

class EditEntryDialog : DialogFragment() {

    private val TAG = "come.asadi.paper.editDialog"

    private var _binding: EditEntryDialogBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val args: EditEntryDialogArgs by navArgs()
    private val editViewModel: PaperViewModel by viewModels() {
        PaperFactory(args.paperId)
    }
    private lateinit var filePath: String
    private lateinit var fileName: String


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), theme)


        return dialog
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.DialogTheme
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = EditEntryDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        // REGISTER DOCUMENT LAUNCHER
        val documentLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri: Uri? ->
                if (uri != null) {
                    // Do something with the selected document URI
                    // CONVERT CONTENT URI TO ACTUAL URI AND GET ACTUAL FILE NAME / PATH
                    // FILE NAME:
                    val contentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
                    val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
                    val fileNameColumnIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                    cursor?.moveToFirst()
                    fileName = cursor?.getString(fileNameColumnIndex!!).toString()
                    cursor?.close()
                    // FILE PATH:
                    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

                    //CREATE FOLDER myPdfs
                    val directory = File(
                        requireContext().filesDir, "myPdfs"
                    ) // Create a File object for the directory
                    directory.mkdirs() // Create the directory if it doesn't already exist
                    // COPY OUTPUT FILE TO APP SUB-DIRECTORY
                    val outputFile = File(
                        directory, fileName
                    ) // Use cacheDir or another appropriate directory for your use case
                    outputFile.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
                        inputStream?.copyTo(outputStream)
                    }

                    // RELEASE INPUT STREAM
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            inputStream?.close()
                        }
                    }


                    filePath = outputFile.absolutePath


                } else {
                    // Handle error or cancellation
                }

            }


        binding.addFileBtn.setOnClickListener {
            // LAUNCHING OPEN DOCUMENT FUNCTION
            val mimeTypes =
                arrayOf("application/pdf") // Set the MIME type of the document you want to select
            documentLauncher.launch(mimeTypes)
        }


        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {

                editViewModel.paper.collect { paper ->

                    if (paper == null) {

                        // DO SOMETHING
                    } else {
                        binding.apply {
                            titleEdittext.hint = paper.title
                            reviewEdittext.hint = paper.review
                        }
                        binding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener {

                            val newTitle = binding.titleEdittext.text.toString()
                            val newReview = binding.reviewEdittext.text.toString()

                            val updatedPaper =
                                Paper(args.paperId, newTitle, newReview, fileName, filePath)

                            editViewModel.updateTask(updatedPaper)

                            dismiss()

                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }


    }


}
```

**2 Viewmodels, one  to get list and other with paperId**

```
package com.asadi.paprr

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.util.*

class PapersListViewModel  : ViewModel() {

    private val paperRepository = PaperRepository.get()



      private val _papers: MutableStateFlow<List<Paper>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
      val papers: StateFlow<List<Paper>>
          get() = _papers.asStateFlow()




    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            paperRepository.getPapers().collect {
                _papers.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun addPaper(paper: Paper) {
        paperRepository.addPaper(paper)
    }

    suspend fun removePaper(paper: Paper) {
        paperRepository.removePaper(paper)
    }








}
```

other view model:

```
package com.asadi.paprr

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.util.*

class PaperViewModel(paperId: UUID) : ViewModel() {


    private val paperRepository = PaperRepository.get()


      private val _paper: MutableStateFlow<Paper?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
      val paper: StateFlow<Paper?> = _paper.asStateFlow()


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _paper.value = paperRepository.getPaper(paperId)
        }
    }
    suspend fun addPaper(paper: Paper) {
        paperRepository.addPaper(paper)
    }

    suspend fun removePaper(paper: Paper) {
        paperRepository.removePaper(paper)
    }


    fun updateTask(paper: Paper) = viewModelScope.launch {
        paperRepository.updatePaper(paper)
    }

 

}

class PaperFactory(
    private val paperId: UUID
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(PaperViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return PaperViewModel(paperId) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

**My recycler adapter code:**

```
package com.asadi.paprr


import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.asadi.paprr.databinding.SingleCardLayoutBinding
import java.util.*



class RecyclerAdapter(
    var papers: List<Paper>, private val editBtnClicked: (paperId: UUID) -> Unit, private val pdfBtnClicked : (paperId : UUID) -> Unit,
   private val removeBtnClicked : (paper : Paper) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    class ViewHolder(private val binding: SingleCardLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


        fun bind(
            paper: Paper,
            editBtnClicked: (paperId : UUID) -> Unit,
            pdfBtnClicked: (paperId : UUID) -> Unit,
            removeBtnClicked: (paper : Paper) -> Unit


        ) {

            binding.paperTitle.text = paper.title
            binding.paperBody.text = paper.review
            binding.paperFileName.text = paper.fileName
            binding.paperFilePath.text = paper.filePath



            binding.editItemBtn.setOnClickListener {

                editBtnClicked(paper.id)

            }


            binding.paperFileName.setOnClickListener {

                pdfBtnClicked(paper.id)

            }

            binding.removeItemBtn.setOnClickListener {

                removeBtnClicked(paper)
            }

        }


    }


    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        val binding = SingleCardLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }


    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element

        val paper = papers[position]
        viewHolder.bind(paper, editBtnClicked, pdfBtnClicked, removeBtnClicked)


    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = papers.size


}
```